# Reading XML node based on element?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlnode

I have a sample xml

```
<UserSettings>
   <Source>settings/subscriptions</Source>
   <DestinationController>UserSettings</DestinationController>
   <DestinationAction>GetUserPreferenceSettings</DestinationAction>
</UserSettings>
```

The reading of the XML using tag name(UserSettings) is done as shown below.

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
strFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlRoutingPath"].ToString();
strFileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + strFileName);

xmlDoc.Load(strFileLocation);

XmlNodeList xmlNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("UserSettings");
```

How do i read directly based on element "Source" ( example for m y above xml : read by passing settings/subscriptions to match the "Source" element ?) I know its real basics, but really confused!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Hi AVD, Do you need any more info?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Linq-XML` (import System.Xml.Linq namespace).

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
string value = doc.Root.Element("Source").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) instead, in combination with [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx) that accepts an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression. The following is untested:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
strFileName = [...]
doc.Load(strFileName);
sourcetext=doc.SelectSingleNode("/UserSettings/Source").InnerText;
```

Edit:

Here's a rough example on how to get the DestinationController based on Source.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
strFileName = [...]
doc.Load(strFileName);
dctext=doc.SelectSingleNode("/UserSettings/[Source=\"Your desired source\"]/DestinationController").InnerText;
```

Comment: thank you, what will the sourcetext contain? COz based on that I need to read the corresponding DstinationController and action , How do I do that?

Comment: `sourcetext` will contain the text of the `<Source>` tag and its children.

Comment: ok is it possible to get the node tag(Usersetting) based on element(source)?

Comment: Yes, you can do that either in your own code or directly in the xpath expression.

Comment: Added a new xpath expression.

Comment: I guess I got it all wrong, What Value I will have is "settings/subscriptions"(that is thw source value,) and nothing else, from that I need to find DestinationController, I wouldnt know the Root node too, So is there some way for that?